# Jest: nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to validate two *getBoudingClientRect* function returns on my application test but I'm getting an error when i try to validate the return of the second.

The first is in an HTMLElement that I search for by ID, so far it's ok. In the test, I can mock your return as follows:

HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = jest.fn();

But, the second element is an ElementRef and I get his info by accessing through the nativeElement, and even though i tried mock his return by any ways I've always get the same error when I try to get this values in my component:

*TypeError: el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect is not a function*

Could anyone help me work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just updating, I've find the problem. To test the method that I've created, I needed mock an ElementRef and pass some properties to it, then I was getting the error message because I hasn't tell my element that getBoundingClientRect is a function. So, instead try to put a Mock anywhere else, I just needed to mock this function and its returns in my ElementRef declaration like this:

```
 const el = new ElementRef({ 
      getBoundingClientRect() { 
        return {
        
        }
      }
    });
```

It worked for me. Although it's not an error but a misuse of the tool, I hope it helps whoever is going through the same doubt.